# Filter elasticsearch parent document when all nested documents match term condition

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a parent document with a nested document within it:

```
parent_mapping = {
  _id: { path: "id" },
  properties: {
    id: { type: "integer" },
    content: { type: "string" },
...
    children: {
      type: "nested",
        properties: {
          id:             { type: "integer" },
          main_entry:     { type: "boolean" },
...
```

I want to get all parent documents where all of the nested documents have main_entry set as "false".

```
filter: {
    nested: {
      path: "entries",
      filter: {
        not: {
          term: { "entries.main_entry" => "true" }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

This is currently giving me all parents that have any nested document with main_entry set to "false".

I'm struggling to exclude results that have nested children with main_entry set to "true".

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that the filter was not applying the condition to all nested entries; rather, it was filtering out documents that have 0 entries matching the condition. My coworker pointed out that by moving the negation outside of the nested filter, I could get my desired result.

```
      filter: {
        not: {
          nested: {
            path: "entries",
            filter: {
              term: { "entries.main_entry" => "true" }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```